# Saving the query object of one Django-Model into another

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django.
I want to save the queried instance of Model-A,'Q' into Model-B. Model-A corresponds to Database D1
and Model-B to D2.
In simple terms something like:

```
Q=queryset(A).using('D1')
Q.save(database='D2',model='Model-B')
```

I this case, ‘A’ and ‘B’ are not the same kind of models, but the queryset used on ‘A’, returns the fields identical to those of ‘B’.

I realise this can be achieved by using a simple for loop to copy instance_A into instance_B and then use save(), but is there a way to do it by passing some arguments to save like save(model=‘B’, using=‘DB2’)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [Manually selecting a database for a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset) and [Selecting a database for save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save).

My guess is that you should only use one model (if they have the same exact fields).

I'm not sure if the code below will work as is, but something like that.

```py
queryset = A.objects.using('D1').all()
for instance in queryset:
    instance.save(using='D2')
```

Comment: I this case, ‘A’ and ‘B’ are not the same kind of models, but the queryset used on ‘A’, returns the fields identical to those of ‘B’. That being the case, can still I use ‘instance.save(using=‘DB2’)’ to achieve the desired results?